# Origen de "braga" como prenda para el cuello [NSFW]

Tags: etimología, historia, ropa, polisemia

En español, por "braga" se pueden entender principalmente dos cosas:

- "Braga" (normalmente "bragas", en plural) como ropa interior femenina:
  *[imagen oculta, pasa el cursor por encima si necesitas una imagen para saber de qué prenda hablo - [NSFW](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/NSFW)]*

> [image]

- "Braga" como prenda de abrigo para el cuello:

> [image]

Me llama la atención que, según el DLE, ambas acepciones tengan el mismo origen:

> [**braga**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=61xXPis)<sup>1</sup>
>   Del lat. *braca* o *bracae* 'calzones', voz de or. galo, y este quizá de or. germ.
>
> 1. f. Prenda interior femenina e infantil, que cubre desde la parte inferior del tronco y tiene dos aberturas en las piernas. *U. m. en pl. con el mismo significado que en sing.*
> 2. f. Prenda de abrigo similar a una bufanda cerrada, pero de tejido más fino.

¿En qué momento y por qué pasó esta palabra de significar "calzón" a significar "bufanda"?

Comment: Mapa de diccionarios muestra que la entrada de _braga_ para el cuello ha ido cambiando prácticamente en cada edición. Luego veo que hay quien sostiene que tiene posible origen distinto: _Viene de la reducción de "Briaga" que era el nombre que recibía la maroma gruesa de esparto que se usaba para sujetar el pie de la uva al prensarla. Parece ser que esta cuerda se llamaba así porque siempre acababa empapada del mosto, por lo que se refería a ella como "la borracha" ("ebriaca", del adjetivo latino "ebrius")._ https://www.minoriadeunosolo.es/2016/06/de-donde-viene-el-nombre-de-la-braga-de.html

Comment: @fedorqui ese segundo origen aparece en el DLE  también pero con otro significado: http://dle.rae.es/?id=61zcRk6

Comment: ¿Ya miraste esto?  https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braga_(prenda_de_vestir)

Comment: No veo nada que es "NSFW". :/

Comment: Well, no.... more that the spoiler tag is completely unnecessary :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay quien sostiene que tiene posible origen distinto. De [¿De dónde viene el nombre de la "Braga de cuello" o "Braga militar?](https://www.minoriadeunosolo.es/2016/06/de-donde-viene-el-nombre-de-la-braga-de.html):

> Viene de la reducción de "Briaga" que era el nombre que recibía la maroma gruesa de esparto que se usaba para sujetar el pie de la uva al prensarla. Parece ser que esta cuerda se llamaba así porque siempre acababa empapada del mosto, por lo que se refería a ella como "la borracha" ("ebriaca", del adjetivo latino "ebrius").

Habida cuenta que la *braga* que tratamos aquí es una *Prenda de abrigo similar a una bufanda cerrada, pero de tejido más fino*, se parece en buena medida a lo que se define arriba. Es decir, una prenda que envuelve.

Por tanto, y sin tener documentos que lo acrediten, a mí me da la sensación que por algún tipo de error esta palabra se está relacionando con la etimología incorrecta y probablemente debería aparecer junto a la segunda entrada de la palabra en el DRAE.